# Autoloading form_validation library

Tags: codeigniter

I am having problem autoloading the `form_validation` library in Codeigniter. I have a controller `Posts` with a create function which works great.

```
public function create(){
       $data['title']='New Post';

              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
}
```

Now I want to do form validation . Something like this :

```
public function create(){
       $data['title']='New Post';
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[128]');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Blog','trim|required|min_length[5]');
       if($this->form_validation->run==FALSE){
              $data['errors']=validation_errors();
              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
       }else {
              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/success', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
       }
}
```

For now I am not calling any `model` to store the data, just showing the success message by loading `posts/success` view . However , even before I code the create function with the validation(that is the above code) , the moment  I add `form_validation` in the `autoload.php` (even with the first code) like so :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','form_validation');
```

I am getting the below error :

> Message: Undefined property: Post_model::$load
>
> Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
>
> Line Number: 147
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\ciblog\index.php Line: 292 Function:
>   require_once

I do not understand the error as I am not even using the `Post_model` in the method .

My `Post_model.php` is :

```
class Post_model extends CI_Controller {
public function get_post($slug=NULL){
   if(!$slug) {
     $query = $this->db->get('posts');  
     return  $query->result();

  } else {
     $this->db->where('slug',$slug);
     $query = $this->db->get("posts");
     return $query->result();
  }
 } 
}
```

My complete post controller is this :

```
<?php
class Posts extends CI_Controller {
public function index(){
    $data['title']='Latest Posts';
    $posts=$this->post_model->get_post();
    $data['posts']=$posts;
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
public function view($slug){
    $posts=$this->post_model->get_post($slug);
    if(empty($posts)){
        show_404();
    } else {
       $data['posts']=$posts;
       $this->load->view('templates/header');
       $this->load->view('posts/view',$data);
       $this->load->view('/templates/footer');
    }   
}
public function create(){
       $data['title']='New Post';
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[128]');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Blog','trim|required|min_length[5]');
       if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
              $data['errors']=validation_errors();
              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer');   
       }else {
              $this->load->view('templates/header');
              $this->load->view('posts/success', $data);
              $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
       }
   }
}
```

I have autoladed the model which is working .I searched other posts , most were to do with the first letter of the model name being not in caps which is not my case . Could somebody please make me understand whats going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used your model in your controller without loading it, you have to load it first:

```
$this->load->model('post_model');
```

Another error here is that model extends `CI_Model`:

```
class Post_model extends CI_Model
```

Comment: I have auto-loaded the model .

Comment: Huge thanks . You just saved me from some serious frustration .

Comment: I know that habbit of copying the controller class and paste it in the model file to save some typing but my susgession to you is to create a snippet for this and that.

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says [ref](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#form-validation-tutorial) you have to validate like this :

I have seen mistake behind the **run()** method

Please fix it with :

`if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`

Also you can check by loading form_validation library directly by updating your constructor

```
public function  __construct()
  {
     parent::__construct();
     $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->load->helper('form');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeIgniter 4.x try this:

**Option 1: Using Autoloader**

Add "form" and "url" helpers

```
public $helpers = ['form', 'url'];
```

**Option 2: Using helper method**

Add the below line in Controller - where you want form_validation required

```
helper(['form', 'url']);
```